# Is there a benefit to pack third-party JS & CSS libraries along with my project assets?

Tags: html, performance, cdn, minify

I want to start using minifying tools such as [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/), [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to speed up the loading of my pages.

My project relies on several bulky libraries ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), ...).

I'm considering two options:

### Option 1: use an official CDN

- Minify only my project files into one `.css` and one `.js` file
- Serve the (minified) major libraries from a renowned [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

This would look like this:

```html
<script src="(my cdn)/myproject.min.js"></script>
<script src="(official cdn)/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="(official cdn)/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="(official cdn)/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="(official cdn)/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(my cdn)/myproject.min.css"></link>
```

Pros:

- Visitors might already have a cached version of some of the libraries, served by the same official CDN from another website, thus avoiding redundant transfers.

Cons:

- If they don't, this approach will require several HTTP calls (even if they do actually, they will still make a request and get a `304 Not Modified`), and this will increase the page load time.

### Option 2: pack everything together

- Minify my project files + the source files of every library, into one single huge file.

This would look like this:

```html
<script src="(my cdn)/myproject-and-libraries.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(my cdn)/myproject-and-libraries.min.css"></link>
```

Pros:

- Number of HTTP calls limited to the strict minimum.

Cons:

- Even if the user has already loaded the jQuery & Bootstrap code from another website, he will have to reload the whole stuff from mine.

### Final note

In either case, I will serve the static files (only the ones compiled by myself) from my own CDN at [AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), so the question is not about using a CDN or not, or which one is better.

The real question is: **pack the third-party libraries with my own, or not?**

Comment: "even if they do actually [have the file cached], they will still make a request and get a 304 Not Modified" - not necessarily. HTTP cache headers can suggest that browsers don't check for a new version of the file until a future date. (See e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching) Granted, the CDN versions of the libraries might not do that. (Or might only do it for URLs that refer to specific versions of the library.)

Comment: @Paul D. Waite You have a point, thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

You should try packing everything together, measure the file size, and see how much space you save versus separate library files. You can at least then compare that saving against other factors.

How you balance HTTP requests vs. total bytes is pretty much up to you. If lots of your users are on mobile connections, additional HTTP requests might be of more concern, because of the extra latency you tend to get on mobile connections.

I think under both options in modern browsers, the HTTP requests will be made in parallel (even old browsers would make two HTTP requests at once per domain). Not sure about mobile browsers.

It's difficult to judge how many users are likely to have the library CDN version already cached when they first visit your site. I think I remember reading something that suggested it was fewer users than you might think (possibly some data from Yahoo, where about 25% of users had it cached), but I can't find the reference.

It's worth considering how often you're expecting the various files to change. If you update your own JavaScript every week or two, but keep your libraries and plugins on the same version for months/years, then it might well be worth keeping those files separate so that returning users don't have to re-download one big packed file just because you changed one line of your own JavaScript.

To be honest though, if you're already minifying, gzipping AND serving from CloudFront, then when people do download files from you, they're going to be coming down pretty damn quickly anyway. And after each user's first empty-cache visit to your site, your files will be cached too. Overall I don't think you'll see a big difference between these options.

One definite drawback of 3rd-party CDNs is that you have no power at all to fix them if they go wrong.

Comment: So if we forgot a minute about the third-party CDNs, and serve everything from CloudFront, would you personally serve each `.min.js` library (maybe a dozen, including jQuery plugins) separately, or would you group them all together? Or even do a mix of this, such as packing jQuery plugins with my own code, but serving the official `boostrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` separately? A little bit of concurrent downloads (as you mentionned, browsers can download several files at a time) could even actually improve the speed a tiny bit?

Comment: @Benjamin: ah sure. I'd probably think about which files were likely to change during the lifecycle of the site. E.g. my own JavaScript might change relatively frequently, but my copy of jQuery 1.7.1 could be cached for a year or two. For unchanging files, assuming you're telling browsers to cache them for a long time, they only get downloaded when a user comes to your site with an empty cache. Possibly making that initial download 10ms faster isn't really something worth worrying about (as addictive as it can be).

Comment: Aah, that good old "it depends"... Thanks for your wise comments anyway!

Comment: @Benjamin: (I don't *think* concurrent downloading of two files would be faster than downloading those two files smooshed together, because the two files smooshed together would probably have fewer bytes after gzip works its magic.)

Comment: True, I was just considering the fact that on many internet connections, you actually gain speed by paralleling downloads (up to a limit).

Comment: @Benjamin: precisely. Weighing up saved bytes versus your one file getting downloaded more often is pretty site-specific. On CloudFront, remember that you're charged every time an end user downloads a file. Reducing the number of times files are downloaded across a year could save you money.

Comment: @Benjamin: oh really? Sure, again that's something you might have to experiment with, and could vary between different end users.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There gets a size point where splitting into two files downloaded in parallel is faster than a single file but it depends on many factors e.g. initcwnd size, whether there's a connection available etc. - I use a rule of thumb of around 75KB gzipped size but it always need measuring and comparing against RUM data

Comment: @AndyDavies: Oh really? Good stuff — is there any good long-form discussion about this that you could link to? (Acronym check: what’s RUM data?)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Will check if I can find a good discussion or will write one if necessary (my knowledge comes from some people in the web perf industry and working with my clients, performance is my day job). RUM = Real User Monitoring, essentially using Navigation Timing API to time how long a page takes to load in the users browser

Comment: @AndyDavies: gotcha - I suspected a lot of this would depend on the end user's set-up. Really interesting stuff, I'd love to see more info on it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Certainly does e.g. if you've got lots of users on a browser that doesn't support many parallel connections e.g. IE6, then it may make more sense to have fewer larger files, if you've got 6 parallel connections that you may need more files but smaller. SPDY/HTTP2.0 will change all this again of course

Comment: What happens if `library_a` and `library_b` have some of the same function names and you concat and minify them together?  Won't all the correct references get broken?