# Is packing JS lib/plugins and maybe CSS files into a single file a right thing?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I know nowadays developers want to reduce the number of requests a webpage sends that includes JavaScript and CSS files and there are some task runners and packers like Webpack and gulp that help you to pack all the scripts and styles either from your own work and/or a plugin/lib into one script file, but the question is, is this a right thing to do?

for example a project that uses `react` , `redux`, `react-redux` can have a single script file that includes all these lib plus the project scripts , perhaps uglified/minified for like +1MB.

as many websites or web apps currently use such lib, isn't it better that those lib are added from some CDNs which helps users to not re-download them if their browser already cached ?

Hope my question is clear enough :)
cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a benefit to pack third-party JS & CSS libraries along with my project assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874158/is-there-a-benefit-to-pack-third-party-js-css-libraries-along-with-my-project)

Comment: you are correct in your assumption to reduce requests, hence possibly including css and js into a single file. I don't see this as a duplicate but possibly it is the right thing to do, it depends on your situation. most bundlers do this for you, if you put the files in the same directory but please don't fall into the 'duplicate trap to get upvotes' and ignore your plight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The better solution is code-splitting. Where you have multiple small files, which are going to be loaded only when required. This can be accomplished using webpack too. The "best" solution is to have, for example, react+redux in a single file and this be downloaded straight away. If other dependencies are not required for the whole application, they should be lazy-loaded.

A perfect scenario:

Given you have a vendor.js containing react + redux (used in the whole application).

A single page which for example, you import moment.js.

User enters website --> downloads react+redux bundle (cached now) -> goes to the other page -> downloads moment.js file.

Something around these lines.

Useful resouce: https://medium.com/webpack/predictable-long-term-caching-with-webpack-d3eee1d3fa31 (using webpack 3, but easily translatable to webpack 4).
Also look for splitChunks on webpack docs (https://webpack.js.org)

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean having more requests when HTML is rendering in this case is a worth than packing everything in a single file?

Comment: Yes, but sort of. You would have more necessary (pay attention on this word) requests when the user first enters the page and small requests when one navigates over the website. The user won't need to download the first big bundle again because it is cached.

Comment: Read more about splitChunks on webpack docs. Also read this: https://medium.com/webpack/predictable-long-term-caching-with-webpack-d3eee1d3fa31 (using webpack 3, but you can still translate to webpack 4)

Comment: Hm.. thanks.. that's a good way of seeing this, but what if the project is a single page app? do you think it's still possible to load the lib in different moments?

Comment: I'm going to try this method, thanks for sharing your thought,.. while I up-voted your answer, I would still let this question stay unanswered to see if I can get another solution.. if not I'll accept it in coming days.

Comment: No problem, but code-splitting is the way to go nowadays, specially with webpack rocking the interwebs.